# How to split a column data with commas and call it into asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, datalist

In a datalist I need to call a table column (terms and conditions i stored in a single column) how can i separate it in asp.net datalist with the help of .cs file with the help of commas it should come as a list.

Comment: Please provide your data schema and sample data.

Comment: you can do it in in the item databound event. also always provide some code and table structure which asking such questions

Comment: In the table I have 3 fields like id, type and terms&conditions in a single column.

Comment: Please read the help guides [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide some sample code and the data.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can deserialize a record to your Type.
for example :

```
        var t = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<t_User>( @"{id:'123' , Name: 'name' , Famili:'family'}");
```

each records has fetched from db should deserialize to your type.